# Display specific row from API in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, arraylist

Iam trying to write a map function to show all the item in API

[ScreenShoot of code to display the items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfOwO.png)

[and this is the console log of the item that fetch from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCQOx.png)

I got Error for the map function that isn't working what is the solution

Thank you

Comment: Please, provide full example of code.

Comment: If you post images of code or error messages, please also copy/paste or type the actual code/message directly into the post. While images and screenshots can be helpful for providing context, the post should still be clear and useful without them. Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273) Posts in which essential text is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell from the picture.
But if I understood correctly you have no return.
Note that you can only have one div in the return.

```
export default function Feed(props) {
    const array1=props.graphDataa.value

  return (
    <div>
      {
        postsArr.map(item=> (whatever you want to display...)) 
      }

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your div is closed in the opening tag - "taskcolorblack-div"
2. You need return value from method listmap like this: `return map1;`
3. In render function u can call like this `return (<>{listmap().join()}</>)`